# Reacting to touch events outside of a specific control

Tags: android, touch

In a `ListFragement` I want to display additional edit options next to an item after the user long-clicks onto it.

This works fine using the following code in a custom `ArrayAdapter` (inside `getView`):

```
rowView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //Show the edit controls
        View editArea = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editArea);
        editArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Don't raise additional events for this touch
        return true;
    }
});
```

However, my problem is which event to use in order to hide those additional edit controls.

Ideally, when the edit controls are displayed, any touch outside them should be ignored in favor of hiding them (a little bit like when a dialog is opened and the user clicks somewhere besides it).

I tried overwriting `dispatchTouchEvent` in my MainActivity - if I generally intercept all `ACTION_DOWN` events, however, my edit controls are hidden before the click is dispatched to them (of course).
Is there any possibility to detect which control the user has touched without already dispatching the event?

If I intercept all `ACTION_UP`s, the edit-controls are removed when the user ends their long-click. And I am trying to avoid whether a specific `ACTION_UP` belongs to the long touch as this would produce some really messy code.

Any ideas which event to listen to?
Or do you know any better, alternate way to achieve my goal?

Comment: why not just having a little "x" on the top right of your edit controls which makes them disappear?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, they appear inline (about text height) so an X would be either so small to be unusable or had to be almost as big as the controls themselves.